# Azure Devops "Deployment Targets" ON PREM

Tags: azure, yaml, azure-pipelines, devops, agent

I am trying to do something in Azure Devops (YAML) that I would achieve in Octopus Deploy using deployment targets and roles. Whilst deploying on prem.

We segregate our agent pools into App/Environment pots. So that from a permissions perspective each agent in the pool can only deploy to a given environment and for a given app (using specific local agents).

I am expecting to be able to say I "run this deployment for all the agents that meet some criteria" be that all the agents in a pool, or that have a demand or capability.

Given each pool is for an app and environmental I want to be able to say 'run this deployment for them all'.

I don't want to have hard code my pipeline or give it knowledge of where applications are deployed.

Like I say in Octopus you just specify a role and all the deployment targets that have that role are used.

Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> you just specify a role and all the deployment targets that have that role are used

There is no such role in Azure DevOps. As a workaround, you can use [Environment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/environments?view=azure-devops) in a deploy job with [rolling deployment strategy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/deployment-jobs?view=azure-devops#rolling-deployment-strategy-1). You can add different tags to the VMs inside the environment, which give you a way to target a set of specific VMs in an environment for deployment.

```
jobs: 
- deployment: VMDeploy
  displayName: VMDeploy
  environment:
    name: Dev
    resourceType: VirtualMachine
    tags: tag1
  strategy:
    rolling:
      maxParallel: 3  
      deploy:
        steps:
```

In the above example, up to 3 VMs in the environment named "Dev" can be deployed in parallel, and these VMs all have "tag1".

Comment: Does that work FOR ON PREM resources? I have been reading hits it works for VMs regardless of where they were created but i am sure I tried it and it would only work for azure vms

Comment: It works for on prem resource. You can follow the steps [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/environments-virtual-machines?view=azure-devops#add-a-resource) to add your local machine as a VM resource.

Comment: It has worked a charm. Thank you.